# When animating an element at high speed in CSS it disappears while in motion

Tags: css, animation

Here I am testing a bouncing ball animation, the code:

```
    #bounce_ball{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius:100%;
    animation-name: bounce;
    animation-duration:.4s;
    background-color: blue;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
@keyframes bounce{
    from{
        transform:   translateY (500px);
    }
    to{
        transform:   translateY (0);
    }
}
```

The code above works, but while the ball is in motion it kind disappear. If anyone can explain to me why this happens and if it a natural thing in CSS animation or not.

Comment: It does not disappear on my laptop, Windows10, Edge. What system/browser/hardware are you using?

Comment: So turns out this bug only shows in chrome browser.